# Semantic UI Dropdown not working correctly

Tags: angular, dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the semantic ui dropdown, but it does not appear correctly in the angular component even if i use all of implementations existing in the official page.

my jquery version : "jquery": "^3.6.0"

here's my html component :

```
<select name="states" class="ui selection dropdown col-md-4" multiple="" id="multi-select">
  <option value="">States</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

and my ts component :

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCountry: any = null;
  countries: any[] = [];
  constructor(private titleService:Title) {
    this.titleService.setTitle('Paramètres');
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    $('#multi-select').dropdown();
  }
}
```

my result is :

[image]